# Windows command line - Outputfile name set from variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, output

I have got some files and i am looping through all of them

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN (%%~nxG) DO (
REM DO STUFF....
                     ) > %%~nxG
```

I already tried to give only the filename specified in %%~nxG to > output file name.

If i try this how it is stated here, it will create the first file with the correct name, but all other files won´t be created. For all the other files it says, that file blabla was not found or does not exist (says for every file except the first one)

So how can i solve that?

I also want to set the path where the new %%~nxG should be created. So for example

```
set newPath="C:/USERS/DESKTOP/TEST/"
```

that i get something like

```
FOR LOOP BLA BLA  > %newPath% %%~nxG
```

So it should create a file with the same name as looped through.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If "usebackq" is specified, perhaps a command should be given. I am not sure that "delims=" has meaning in the case of a filename?

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN (`DIR /B %%~nxG`) DO (
```